# Change domain based on location

Tags: 7, multi-sites, uri

I want to create one website for multi-countries and each country's website content should be different according to the selection. But the file and database should be single.
For example,
For Singapore version: example.com/sg/
For Honk kong version: example.com/hk/
The website is redirected based on the user location and can also be switched manually. When a user from Singapore enters the url it first redirects to the example.com/sg/. There should also be an option to switch the domain manually by the user. If user selects Honk Kong manually the website is redirected to example.com/hk/. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

U can take client ip and then use some library like [Geocoder](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder) to create redirection based on country.